# If Orcus is an Imaginary Friend, then who is his "real person"?

Tags: happy

Towards the end of the second season of "Happy!", Nick and Merry meet Orcus, the god of death. To protect himself, Orcus uses his power and forces any bystander to attempt to commit suicide.

Then enters Happy, who discovers that he has the power to

> Make people madly want/love each other. Hilarity and squick ensue.

[image]

This surprises everyone, including Orcus, who manages to mumble "You are like me!"

So, based on the fact that in the finale Happy

> meets God

who is an Imaginary Friend to the whole civilisation, can we get to a conclusion that Orcus is also an IF? If so, to whom? As far as I know, an Imaginary Friend cannot exist without his real person (and that someones believe/love/need) and we've seen many such Friends disappearing when the children suddenly were exposed to something traumatic (like Sonny Shine sex tape).

Answer (score 1):

Orcus now resides in Nick. Recall that an Imaginary Friend can exist for more than one person (God is an imaginary friend to all of humanity). Orcus was Sonny Shine’s IF but when Amanda shot Shine at the Eggtacular, he was free to own another host. Nick jumped in front of Hailey’s bullet killing him but Happy noticed that he was not vanishing. Then we see the dialogue with the God of Death, explaining that Nick hates Smoothie so much he refuses to die knowing what will happen to the children:

> NICK: "Revenge"? I don't have a vengeful bone in my body.
> ORCUS: Oh, Nick, don't be tedious.
> Of course you do.
> Everybody loves revenge.
> I mean, can you really shuffle off to the great beyond knowing that the man who bested you is still out there somewhere? Can you? You know who I'm talking about.
> Tick, tock, time to rock.
> I'm going to show you why they call me Smoothie.
> Yes.

The God of Death allows Nick to live only on the condition that Orcus owns him. So, Orcus is now in Nick.

Source: [ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/happy-unanswered-questions-canceled/)

Comment: I don't buy it. 1) Orcus is the god of death and he was inside one of the shot Blue's nephews until he got offloaded into Blue. 2) Sonny has never seen Orcus as IF until he was possessing Blue's body. 3) We know that Orcus might die if the last Scaramucci would die -> So I believe that Orcus is IF to the whole Scaramucci mafia family

Comment: IFs can have many hosts (e.g. God) and hosts can have many IFs. There might not be a single person answer, but Orcus “owns” Nick now. We’d probably get a better answer if season 3 wasn’t canx

Comment: I personally think this was a trick. Orcus was in danger and needed Nick to live to be his friend (because Orcus’ friend was dying?) Again no season 3, no solid answer. And in season 3 we were going to find out Nick Sax is “Santa Clause” (the real St. Nick)

Comment: Also the Scaramuccis don’t need to die, just stop believing.